# Populating an association with children in factory_girl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, unit-testing, factory, factory-bot

I have a model `Foo` that has_many 'Bar'. I have a factory_girl factory for each of these objects. The factory for Bar has an association to Foo; it will instantiate a Foo when it creates the Bar.

I'd like a Factory that creates a Foo that contains a Bar. Ideally this Bar would be created through the :bar factory, and respect the build strategy (create/build) used to create the Foo.

I know I could just call the :bar factory and then grab the Foo reference from the new Bar. I'd like to avoid this; in my test case, the important object is Foo; calling the Bar factory seems a bit circuitous. Also, I can see the need for a Foo with multiple Bars.

Is this possible in factory_girl? How do you define this relationship in the parent?

Answer (score 51, accepted):

The `Factory.after_ hooks` appear to be the only way to do this successfully. I've figured out a way to maintain the build strategy without duplicating code:

```
Factory.define :foo do |f|
  f.name "A Foo"
  f.after(:build) { |foo|
    foo.bars << Factory.build(:bar, :foo => foo)
  }
  f.after(:create) { |foo|
    foo.bars.each { |bar| bar.save! }
  }
end
```

The [documentation](http://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl) states that `after_build` will be called before `after_create` if the `:create` build strategy is used. If `:build` is used, then only `after_build` is called, and everyone is happy.

I've also created an abstracted generally-applicable version [at this gist](http://gist.github.com/436917) to keep things DRY.

Comment: It is hard to believe that this is the best way to do this but It still seems to be the case. Up-voted this answer.

Comment: How do you use your gist version?  What's the best way to incorporate that into a Rails app?

Comment: As noted [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13197359/add-association-without-commiting-to-database), using `<<` to add an association persists the changes. To avoid that, the `after(:build)` should be `foo.association(:bars).add_to_target(Factory.build(:bar, :foo => foo)
)`

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `association` method both ways:

```
Factory.define :foo do |f|
  # ...
  f.association :bar
end
```

If that won't work, you can associate them manually using a callback. Here's an example from one of my apps:

```
Factory.define :live_raid do |raid|
end

Factory.define :live_raid_with_attendee, :parent => :live_raid do |raid|
  raid.after_create { |r| Factory(:live_attendee, :live_raid => r) }
end
```

Comment: The first syntax causes a a stack overflow/infinite recursion in my code.

The second syntax works wonderfully, except that it doesn't obey the build strategy.

Answer (score 3):

FactoryGirl now has a `:method => :build` option you can use on the association, which will build the associated object rather than creating it.

[#64: Building an object creates associations](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/issues/64)

Answer (score 3):

FactoryGirl 4.3.0 is calling `save!` on an association when calling `build` on the parent object, which i believe is not intended to be the correct behavior.

After digging through the FactoryGirl code, adding `strategy: :build` to the association definition in the factory seems now be creating my association without calling `save!`.

Answer (score 2):

Using `factory_girl-4.5.0`, create n child objects in a parent object factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :foo do
    name "test"        

    after(:build) do |instance|
      n.times { instance.bars << FactoryGirl.create(:bar) }          
    end
  end
end
```