# factory_girl_rails has_many association includes only one from a collection of many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations, factory-bot

I'm using [factory_girl_rails](https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl_rails) instead of fixtures. Here are my models:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :tasks
end

class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Here are my factories:

```
Factory.define :user do |u|
end

Factory.define :task do |t|
  t.association :user, :factory => :user
end
```

In a test I do this:

```
user = Factory.create :user
(1..5).each { Factory.create(:task, :user => user)}
```

The problem that I'm experiencing is that afterward `user.tasks` contains only one task.

I have tried defining the `user` factory like this:

```
Factory.define :user do |u|
  u.tasks {|tasks|  [tasks.association(:user)] }
end
```

and like this:

```
Factory.define :user do |u|
  u.tasks {|tasks|  [tasks.association(:user), tasks.association(:user)] }
end
```

In both cases `Factory.create(:user)` causes an infinite loop.

Comment: `(1..5).each { Factory.create(:task, :user => user)}` works fine in console for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ah, this works:

```
Factory.define :task do |t|
  t.association :user
  t.after_create {|t| t.user.tasks << t}
end
```

John, your approach would work but I actually couldn't use what you described because in my test the tasks need to also reference another (unmentioned) model and I don't see a way of referencing it in the `user_with_tasks` factory definition.

Answer (score 3):

I think what you're doing is backwards -- you can create Tasks from the User, but not visa versa like you're trying to do.  Conceptually, the association goes from the user to the task.

What I did was create a special factory for that type of user.

```
Factory.define :user_with_tasks, :parent => :user do |user|
  user.after_create {|u| 5.times { Factory.create(:task, :user => user) } }
end
```

Also, if you just want to use the default factory, you just do this

```
Factory.define :task do |f|
  f.user :user
end
```

No need to specify the factory

**UPDATE:**  Looks like others have done something similar in the past:
[Populating an association with children in factory_girl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2937326/populating-an-association-with-children-in-factory-girl)