# Add association (<<) without committing to database

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is it possible in Rails to add an association to an **existing** record without immediately committing this change to the database?
E.g. if I have Post has_many :tags

```
post.tags << Tag.first
```

This will commit to database immediately. I've tried other ways instead of <<, but without success (what I want is to create the association when saving the parent object).
Is it possible to get behavior like when you are adding association to a new record with build?

```
post.tags.build name: "whatever"
```

I think this is kind of inconsistent in Rails, in some cases it would be useful to have an option to do this.

In other words I want

```
post.tags << Tag.first # don't hit the DB here!
post.save # hit the DB here!
```

Comment: What's wrong with using `build` on the parent object? Can you explain in more detail what you think is inconsistent about it and/or what you wish it looked like in an ideal world? `build` seems to be "built" (if you'll forgive the pun) for this purpose - adding a child/associated object without immediately committing it.

Comment: build works fine, but not when trying to add an association to an already-existing record. I don't see an analogous method to build to add associations to existing records (i mean existing child record here). I updated the question if it makes it more clear now.

Comment: I guess ideally without breaking existing code I would like something like post.tags.build id: Tag.first.id. Can't think of a better semantic for it since <<, push etc. all already have defined behavior of comitting immediately. -_-
Perhaps post.tags.build_to Tag.first. Not sure exactly, I'd just like the option to do that.

Comment: No, you cannot have the syntax that you want. `<<` commits the change

Comment: It's not the syntax I want, it's the functionality. I'm aware what << does. (well, it works like I want in case post is a "new_record?", but that's not of much help)

Comment: @JesseWolgamott This is useful if you want to initialize a child object and add it to a parent, make changes to the parent, and save everything in a single call/transaction by calling save on the parent.

Comment: @JesseWolgamott To be clear, `build` does not allow you to init and preprocess a child object, then assign it to the parent, change the parent, and save both in a single transaction.

Comment: @Mohamad if you have autosave, I an confident it will.

Comment: what about post.post_tags = post.post_tags + [Tag.find(111)] ?

Comment: sounds like it could work depending on implementation, I have to try it

Comment: @igor-kasyanchuk, your suggestions fails in Rails 3.2.18--it saves the record immediately. Could you specify a version where this should work?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

This should work in Rails 3.2 and Rails 4:

```
post.association(:tags).add_to_target(Tag.first)
```

See this gist: https://gist.github.com/betesh/dd97a331f67736d8b83a

Note that saving the parent saves the child and that child.parent_id is NOT set until you save it.

EDIT 12/6/2015:
For a polymorphic record:

```
post.association(:tags).send(:build_through_record, Tag.first)
# Tested in Rails 4.2.5
```

Comment: `post.association(:tags).send(:build_through_record, Tag.first)` do not work for me on 4.2.9 but `post.association(:tags).add_to_target(Tag.first)` works great

Comment: @inye Is this for a polymorphic association?

Comment: Then `add_to_target` should work and `build_through_record` should not, just as you observed.

Answer (score 3):

```
post_tag = post.post_tags.find_or_initialize_by_tag_id(Tag.first.id)
post_tag.save
```

Comment: It does work. I've updated the answer with the correct usage of the code. Rails 4 has a different syntax `find_or_initialize_by(attr_hash)`.

Answer (score 1):

To add to Isaac's answer, `post.association(:tags).add_to_target(Tag.first)` works for `has_many` relationships, but you can use `post.association(:tag).replace(Tag.first, false)` for `has_one` relationships. The second argument (`false`) tells it not to save; it will commit it to the database by default if you leave the argument empty.

Answer (score 0):

**PREFACE**  This is not exactly an answer to this question but somebody searching for this *kind* of functionality may find this useful. Consider this and other options very carefully before wantonly putting it into a production environment.

You can, in some cases, leverage a has_one relationship to get what you want.  Again, really consider what you're trying to accomplish before you use this.

**Code to Consider** 
You have a `has_many` relationship from `Trunk` to `Branch` and you want to add a new branch.

```
class Trunk
  has_many :branches
end

class Branch
  belongs_to :trunk
end
```

I can also relate them to each other singularly. We'll add a `has_one` relationship to the `Trunk`

```
class Trunk
  has_many :branches
  has_one :branch
end
```

At this point, you can do things like `Tree.new.branch = Branch.new` and you'll be setting up a relationship that will not save immediately, but, after saving, will be available from `Tree.first.branches`.

*However*, this makes for quite a confusing situation for new developers when they look at the code and think, "Well, which the hell is it supposed to be, one or many?"

To address this, we can make a more reasonable `has_one` relationship with a `scope`.

```
class Trunk
  has_many :branches

  # Using timestamps
  has_one :newest_branch, -> { newest }, class_name: 'Branch'

  # Alternative, using ID. Side note, avoid the railsy word "last"
  has_one :aftmost_branch, -> { aftmost }, class_name: 'Branch'
end

class Branch
  belongs_to :trunk

  scope :newest, -> { order created_at: :desc }
  scope :aftmost, -> { order id: :desc }
end
```

Be careful with this, but it can accomplish the functionality being asked for in the OP.