# Rails 4.2.6 FactoryGirl with polymorphic association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, factory-bot, rspec-rails

I have a problem setting up factories for my polymorphic associations with FactoryGirl. My model and factory setup looks like this:

```
class Address < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :addressable, polymorphic: true
end

class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_one :address, as: :addressable
end 

factory :address do
      village Faker::Address.city
      upazilla Faker::Address.street_name
      ward Faker::Address.street_address
      district Faker::Address.state
      association :addressable
end


factory :customer ,class: Customer do 
      recharge_token 10 
      date_of_birth Faker::Date.backward(100)
      manager
      after(:create) do |customer| 
         customer.address = create(:address, addressable: customer)
        #create( :address, addressable: customer)
      end     
end
```

The test suite breaks with the following error message

```
 vendor/cache/ruby/2.2.0/gems/factory_girl-4.7.0/lib/factory_girl/linter.rb:12:in `lint!': The following factories are invalid: (FactoryGirl::InvalidFactoryError)
 * address - Factory not registered: addressable (ArgumentError)
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21270041/factory-girl-with-polymorphic-association-for-has-many-and-has-one) is exactly my problem but unfortunately his solution is not working for me. Thanks you all for your time!

Answer (score 9):

Specify factory explicitly:

```
factory :address do
   association :addressable, factory: :customer
end
```

or create the association `has_one` on the other model in the `after create` list:

```
factory :customer do 
   after(:create) do |customer| 
     customer.address = create(:address, addressable: customer)
   end
end
```

Comment: Hey, your top solution is awesome. Can I give this an array? factory: [:customer, :user, :client]